# Filtering in Statamic using Livewire

Tags: laravel-livewire, screen-size, statamic, livewire-3

I'm using Livewire for the first time. I have a Statamic Livewire component that displays a collection of blog articles with a default limit of 9 items. However, I noticed that on mobile devices (less than 768 pixels), I have to reduce the limit to 3 items. I'm trying to figure out how to dynamically adjust the limit based on the screen size.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use Statamic\Facades\Collection;

class FilterCollection extends Component
{
    public $taxonomyField;
    public $taxonomySlug;
    public $collectionName;
    public $viewName = 'collection';
    public $offset = 0;
    public $limit = 9;
    public $q;
    public $defaultSortBy = 'desc';
    public $sortBy;
    public $cards = [
        'blog_articles' => '_blog-list-card',
    ];

    public function render()
    {
        $newEntries = Collection::find($this->collectionName)
        ->queryEntries()
        ->where('published', 1)
        ->orderBy('date', $this->defaultSortBy)
        ->offset($this->offset)
        ->limit($this->limit);

        if (!empty($this->taxonomySlug)) {
            $newEntries->whereTaxonomy($this->taxonomyField . '::' . $this->taxonomySlug);
        }
        if (!empty($this->q)) {
            $newEntries->where(function ($query) {
                $query->where('title', 'like', '%' . $this->q . '%')
                    ->orWhere('article_summary', 'like', '%' . $this->q . '%')
                    ->orWhere('page_builder', 'like', '%' . $this->q . '%');;
            });
        }

        return view('livewire.filter-' . $this->viewName, ['entries' => $newEntries]);
    }

    public function filterCollection($taxonomySlug)
    {
        $this->taxonomySlug = $taxonomySlug;
    }

    public function loadMore()
    {
        $this->limit += $this->limit;
    }

    public function mount($collectionName, $taxonomyField = 'articles_tags', $q = null)
    {
        $this->collectionName = $collectionName ?? 'articles';
        $this->taxonomyField = $taxonomyField;
        $this->q = $q;
    }

}
```

The limit has the value of 9, but on mobile screens I need the limit to be adjusted to 3. How can I do that? I've tried to connect Livewire with Javascript, but I wasn't able to.

Comment: you could use this package riverskies/laravel-mobile-detect, works well with laravel and livewire https://github.com/riverskies/laravel-mobile-detect, it will help you to detect ig agent is desktop or mobile, check git hub link for docs

Comment: @ShubhamSahu do you know if that package also works on Statamic?

Comment: it should, did you tried, i haven't tried statamic yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably try hiding the extra items with CSS media queries rather than doing anything on the backend.

Presuming you're using Antlers, you can do something like this on each item:

```
{{ entries }}
  <div {{ if index > 2 }} style="display: none" {{ /if }}>
    <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
    <!-- whatever other stuff you're doing... -->
  </div>
{{ /entries }}
```

Comment: The issue with that approach is that when I click to load more articles that ones that i'm hiding will not appear. Because the purpose is to have 3 articles on mobile and more 3 when I click on the "load more" button and so on.

Comment: You could try keeping track of the amount of items hidden. On 'load more', check the number of hidden items, if `hiddenItems >= 3` show the next 3 items, if `hiddenItems < 3 && hiddenItems > 0` show all the hiddenItems. If `hiddenItems === 0` load the next limit of items.